# How does $x^2+4xy-6x+4y^2-12y+9=0$ represent a straight line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I need to show $x^2+4xy-6x+4y^2-12y+9=0$ is a straight line. But I only know of a straight line in the form $y=mx+c$. Any help?

Comment: Try calculating $(y-mx-c)^2$

Answer (score 5):

$$x^2+4xy+4y^2-6x-12y+9=0$$
$$(x+2y)^2-6(x+2y)+9=0$$
$$(x+2y-3)^2=0$$
$$x+2y-3=0$$ is a stright line.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is equivalent with
$$(x+2y)^2-6(x+2y)+9 = (x+2y-3)^2 = 0$$
This is equivalent with
$$x+2y-3=0$$
Which is a straight line.

Comment: Why is this a straight line? Also how do you recognize how to factor this?

Comment: @user238962 solve it with respect to $y$.

Comment: Ok got it. one last question how would you recognize that this is $(x+2y-3)^2$

Comment: Actually, because you said so. I just tried the most obvious factorization. There is a general method though. You can find your answer here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align}
0 & = x^2+4y^2+9 + 4xy-6x-12y\\
& = x^2 + (2y)^2 + (-3)^2 + 2\cdot x \cdot (2y) + 2 \cdot x \cdot (-3) + 2 \cdot (2y) \cdot (-3)\\
& = (x+2y-3)^2
\end{align}
This gives us
$$x+2y-3 = 0$$
which indeed is a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone has answered to your question. I will suggest you to study the concept pair of straight lines. After that you will learn that xy=0 represents the two coordinate axes! And much more.
I suggest you read books on this or see tutorials.